# Specific field of a document in MongoDb to Java Object

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to select a specific field of a document in Mongodb collection and convert it to java object.

My document is like this:

```
{
    "Name":"Ben",
    "template":"A fingerprint template which I extracted"
}
```

So I wish select this "template field"

My sample code is below:

```
   List<Document> documents = (List<Document>) collection.find().into(new ArrayList<Document>());
        for (Document document : documents) {
            Document doc = documents.get(document);
            FingerprintTemplate template = (FingerprintTemplate) doc.get("template");
```

And the error is:

> **java: incompatible types: org.bson.Document cannot be converted to int**

Any idea or any suggestions please!!

Comment: Are you using Morphia as ODM?

Comment: No.. Should I use this?

Comment: `template` field is of type string in the document. You want to convert this into Java object - of what _type_?

Comment: There is a [com.machinezoo.sourceafis.FingerprintTemplate](https://sourceafis.machinezoo.com/javadoc/com/machinezoo/sourceafis/FingerprintTemplate.html) class - is it what you are referring to in your code?

Comment: Yes...And  I want to match this template to another fingerprint template

Comment: this is the code where I converted the object into Json: `BasicDBObject obj=(BasicDBObject) JSON.parse(gson.toJson(candidate_template));
        Document doc=new Document("template",obj);` And now, I want to retrieve this

Comment: @MohdShoaib You can use ObjectMapper.readValue() of Jackson Library to typecast your object into Java Object. Hope this might be helpful : 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55147518/how-to-convert-below-json-to-pojo-using-objectmapper-of-jackson/58755128#58755128'

Answer (score 0):

You can query if the field exists:

```
collection.find("template": { $exists: true, $ne: null } });
```

For the mapping part, you can have a look at objectMapper to map directly to a java object: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

Your error is still that you have a Document and Java is expecting an int.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
basicDBObject.put("template",1);
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query,whereQuery);
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```

This would print the documents that have `template` but to convert to Object you would need some `JSON Object mapper` maybe `jackson`

Comment: this line: `DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query,whereQuery);` shows an error **java: no suitable method found for find(com.mongodb.BasicDBObject,com.mongodb.BasicDBObject)**

Comment: complete stack trace? How are you getting a reference to `collection` ?

Comment: ` MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("finger");`